# CSRF Token implementation in Struts 1

Tags: java, csrf, struts-1

We are using synchronizer token to prevent CSRF vulnerability as below

```
1> saveToken(request)
2> <input type="hidden"
   name="<%=org.apache.struts.taglib.html.Constants.TOKEN_KEY%>"
   value="<bean:write name="<%=Globals.TRANSACTION_TOKEN_KEY%>"/>">
3> isTokenValid(request)
```

The fix is not working due to token not being refreshed. what can be causing this.

Also what difference, below code will make

isTokenValid(request,reset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the action that displays your edit page, you call the `saveToken` method.

```
saveToken(request)
```

This generated a **new token** and saves it on the session (the `html:form` tag detects this value and stores it as a **hidden** value on your html form). You don't really need to create an input hidden element in your JSP, cause the `saveToken` method together with `html:form` will create it.

During the action that saves your data, you call the `isTokenValid` method. This method checks that the value submitted matches the token saved on the session.

At this point and if the token is valid, you have two options:

1. You can call `resetToken`, which clears the token on the session. So, if the user submits the page again, the token on the session should be cleared and the second call to `isTokenValid` will fail.
2. Pass true in as the second parameter to `isTokenValid`. This will reset the token after checking it.

   ```
   isTokenValid(request,true)
   ```

You can find more info in Struts API of:

1. [isTokenValid(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request)](http://www.d.umn.edu/~tcolburn/cs4531/struts/api/org/apache/struts/action/Action.html#isTokenValid(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest))
2. [saveToken(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request)](http://www.d.umn.edu/~tcolburn/cs4531/struts/api/org/apache/struts/action/Action.html#saveToken(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest))

Hope this help you.

Comment: Please explain a bit about your solution rather then just referring to another post.